# Passing of value from one activity to another in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi i have developed an app which has a text box and a search button when i enter a number in the text box and click on the search button it needs to pass the value entered to the next activity where it uses that value to get the value from a database.

I am using the following code to pass the value.

```
search_button.setClickable(true);
      search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String outlet_no = outlet_id.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(outlet_no);
        if(!outlet_no.isEmpty()){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();

        prefsEditor.putString("outlet_id", outlet_no);
        prefsEditor.commit();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, StoreActivity.class);       
        startActivity(myIntent);
        HomeActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an outlet id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }  
      }
    });
```

My problem is that it doesnot pass the value. Can any one help me with this and also can any1 explain me the above code as i didnot write it and i am finding it difficult to understand it.

StoreActivity side

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.store);      
        myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);             
        mOutletID = myPrefs.getString("outlet_id", "0");
        mOutletDetails = myPrefs.getString("outlet_details","{}");
        Log.v("outlet_details",myPrefs.getString("outlet_details","{}"));
        if(mOutletDetails != "{}"){
            setOutletData(mOutletDetails);
        }
        else{
            executeAjaxRequest();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mistakes you made:

**1) Why are you trying to start activity twice?**

```
startActivity(myIntent);   // this is OK
HomeActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

**2) To pass entered text from one activity to another, you can use `putExtra()` method of Intent, for example:**

```
myIntent.putExtra("SearchText", outlet_no);
```

So your complete code would be:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, StoreActivity.class);   
 myIntent.putExtra("SearchText", outlet_no);    
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

**3) To receive value which you have passed from first activity:**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String outlet_no= bundle.getString("SearchText");
```

**4) SharedPreferences:**

FYI, `SharedPreference` is used to save small amount of data which can be reference and used later across application.

You should refer below links:

1. [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
2. [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
3. [Intent and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: i didnt write this code and there are many bugs which i am wagging a war to correct...

Comment: @JayantShinde Just go through my answer.

Comment: no not onl these errors i have some more errors can you help me fix it as i am on probation at my workplace and i need to give this as soon as possible and i am finding it difficult to correct as i am not trained on android...

Comment: @JayantShinde `Logcat` is your best friend to solve android errors and for fixes exceptions/issues.

Comment: i dont get logcat errors only this unexpected value in native get enbled methods...

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, StoreActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("searchString", outlet_no);       
startActivity(myIntent);
```

This will send the `searchString` to the `StoreActivity`

and in `StoreActivity` you can retrieve the value using:

```
String s = getIntent.getStringExtra("searchString");
```

Answer (score 2):

In your onClick method, have the following code:

```
    String outlet_no = outlet_id.getText().toString();
    if(!outlet_no.isEmpty()){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, StoreActivity.class);  
        myIntent.putExtra("outlet_id",outlet_no);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an outlet id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

Now in the StoreActivity, in the onCreate() method have something like this:

```
String outlet_no = getIntent().getStringExtra("outlet_id");  
if (outlet_no != null) //Just a defensive check
   //Start your processing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with Intents.

Say, we have 2 activities: SourceActivity & DestinationActivity
and we want to pass a value of SourceActivity to DestinationActivity

in your Button OnClickListener:

```
String str_outlet_no = outlet_no.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(SourceActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("outlet_no_key", outlet_no);
startActivity(intent);
```

and on the other side in DestinationActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String desi = intent.getStringExtra("outlet_no");
```

and search **desi** from database

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

**Activity A**

```
myIntent.putExtra(var, value); // Putting the value
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**Activity B**

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra(var); // Getting the value
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write it as

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, StoreActivity.class);
      myIntent.putExtra("outlet_no",outlet_no);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

Let me know if this worked or not.

Answer (score -1):

Activity A

```
myIntent.putExtra(var, value); // Putting the value
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Activity B

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra(var); // Getting the value
```