# how to pass value from datepicker and timepicker to a TextView in another activity

Tags: android, datepicker

MyMainScreen.java

```
public class MyMainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

// Widget GUI
Button btnCalendar, btnCalendar1, btnTime, btnTime1;
private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// API urls
// Url to get all categories
private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://10.0.2.2/car_rental/get_categories.php";


 // Variable for storing current date and time
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);
    btnTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime);
    btnCalendar1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar1);
    btnTime1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime1);

    btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTime.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCalendar1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTime1.setOnClickListener(this);
    categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    new GetCategories().execute(); 
}

/**
 * Async task to get all food categories
 * */
private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyMainScreen.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching data..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("pickup");                        

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                catObj.getString("name"));
                        categoriesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();
    }

}

/**
 * Adding spinner data
 * */
private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerpick);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ItemSelectedListener());
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerdrop);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ItemSelectedListener());
  }



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     if (v == btnCalendar) {
    // Process to get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Launch Date Picker Dialog
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // Display Selected date in text box
                    btnCalendar.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}

     if (v == btnTime) {

         // Process to get Current Time
         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
         mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

         // Launch Time Picker Dialog
         TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                 new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                     @Override
                     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                             int minute) {
                         // Display Selected time in text box
                         btnTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                     }
                 }, mHour, mMinute, false);
         tpd.show();



}

     if (v == btnCalendar1) {
            // Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd1 = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // Display Selected date in text box
                            btnCalendar1.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd1.show();
        }

             if (v == btnTime1) {

                 // Process to get Current Time
                 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                 mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                 mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                 // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                 TimePickerDialog tpd1 = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                         new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                             @Override
                             public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                     int minute) {
                                 // Display Selected time in text box
                                 btnTime1.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                             }
                         }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                 tpd1.show();



    }

}

public void newActivity(View view){
      Bundle b=new Bundle();
      b.putString("pickup",       spinner1.getItemAtPosition(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());    
      b.putString("dropoff", spinner2.getItemAtPosition(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());

      Intent alarmSet = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CarSelection.class);
      alarmSet.putExtras(b);
      startActivityForResult(alarmSet, 0);

    }

}
```

CarSelection.java

```
public class CarSelection extends Activity {

private Spinner spinner1;

// array list for spinner adapter
private ArrayList<Category> brandsList;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Url to get all categories
private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://10.0.2.2/car_rental/get_brands.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_selection);

     Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b != null){
        String selection1=b.getString("pickup");
        String selection2=b.getString("dropoff");
        TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pickup);
        TextView text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dropoff);
        text1.setText(selection1);
        text2.setText(selection2);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(CarSelection.this,"Haven't Received any data yet",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    brandsList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    new GetCategories().execute(); 
}

/**
 * Async task to get all food categories
 * */
private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CarSelection.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching data..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("brands");                        

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getInt("id"),
                                catObj.getString("name"));
                        brandsList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
            populateSpinner();
    }

}

/**
 * Adding spinner data
 * */
private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int i = 0; i < brandsList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(brandsList.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerbrand);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CarBrandSelection(this));

      }


/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.car_selection, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pick_up" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerpick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
      />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalendar"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Calendar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTime"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/time_picker" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/drop_off" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerdrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalendar1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Calendar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTime1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/time_picker" />

    </LinearLayout>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="newActivity"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that my DatePicker and TimePicker are actually buttons. I want to do like after a user selects the time and date and press next button, the values of date and time will be displayed in the textviews of a new activity.hope you guys can guide me through this.Thank you.

Comment: Use putExtra() for that..Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996597/passing-of-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: @Laljust tried out your way..but no value is returned...:(

Comment: returned means??? You didnt get the values in the next activity or what??? @user3402438

Comment: didn't get the value in next activity.can you show me how to do this?thank you.

Comment: `public void newActivity(View view){
       Intent b=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CarSelection.class);
          b.putExtra("pickup", spinner1.getItemAtPosition(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
          b.putExtra("dropoff", spinner2.getItemAtPosition(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
          
          b.putExtra("year",mYear);  
          b.putExtra("month",mMonth);  
          b.putExtra("day",mDay); 
          
          startActivity(b);

     }`

Comment: **then i have modified this in the onCreate method of new activity**     'Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
   if(b != null){
   String selection1=b.getString("pickup");
   String selection2=b.getString("dropoff");
   b.getInt("year"); 
   b.getInt("month");  
   b.getInt("day"); 
   TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pickup);
   TextView text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dropoff);
   TextView text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
   text1.setText(selection1);
   text2.setText(selection2);
   text3.setText(mYear+"");
         }'

Comment: Are you sure you get values for all those variables?? try showing a toast before startActivity(b)

Comment: @Lali just can just the string value for pickup and dropoff..the problem is now i want to get the values of datepicker and timepicker

Comment: pardon.. i didnt understand you..sry..please be clear.. @user3402438

Answer (score 0):

Use this to "put" the file...

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String keyIdentifer  = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
```

Comment: but the value for the datepicker and timepicker are not string

Comment: ok..then how can i set the values in the textview as the value for date is separated like                                       `b.getString("year");                          b.getString("month");  
                 b.getString("day");`

Comment: showing nullnullnull in textview. Perhaps ther eis problem with the integer value from data and timepicker

Comment: Are you getting value from date and time picker before starting the new intent ???

Comment: yeah..i use putExtra as mentioned by u just now to put the value of date and time..

Comment: no, i asked are the values correctly obtained before passing them to new intent??? check using a Toast or debug..

Comment: **i tried to do this but there is an error in the getMonth,getYear and getDay since my datepicker & timepicker is actually made of buttons**      `month = datePicker.getMonth();  
    day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth(); 
    year = datePicker.getYear();


    intent.putExtra("year",year);  
    intent.putExtra("month",month);  
    intent.putExtra("day",day); `